# Regex: Select everything up to | but not | (between <title></title>)

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I have this example:

`<title>Square Meters | Dragon White (en)</title>`

I want to use regex as to select everything up to `|` but not `|` (between ...)

My 2 regex selects also the `|`, this is why I need a better formula, without that `|`

SEARCH: `\w+.*\|` or  `\w+.*?[\s\S]\|`

This is the line from my Python code, with the regex I must change a little bit:

`words = re.findall(r'\w+', new_filename)`

Right now the result is `square-meters-dragon-white-en.html`

But the expected result should be: `square-meters.html`

This is the part with python code:

```
new_filename = title.get_text() 
new_filename = new_filename.lower()
words = re.findall(r'\w+', new_filename)
new_filename = '-'.join(words)
new_filename = new_filename + '.html'
print(new_filename)
```

I get very close, if I change this way the regex: `(?=\w+).*(?= \|)`

`words = re.findall(r'(?=\w+).*(?= \|)', new_filename)`

and I get: `square meters.html` (but without little dash)

Comment: Please, edit your question and add more sample text **and expected result**. What the python code have to do with the question?

Comment: I edit the post @Toto

Comment: I try now this regex: `\w+.*(?= \|)`

`words = re.findall(r"\w+.*(?= \|)", new_filename)`

almost works, but I get:  `square meters.html`  (but without little dash)

Comment: If I well understand, you want a python script, not an editor solution? Try `r'\b\w+\b(?=[\w\s]+\|)'` then join elements of array with `-`

Comment: I edit again the post @Toto, you should understand better the problem.

Comment: No, I can't. This is a programing question, off topic on superuser ;(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130509/discussion-between-just-me-and-toto).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks @Toto

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `\b\w+\b(?=[\w\s]+\|)`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Find All in Current Document</kbd>

**For your Python code, change with this line:**

`words = re.findall(r'\b\w+\b(?=[\w\s]+\|)', new_filename)`

Answer (score 1):

Use simply: `[^|]+` # 1 or more any character that is not a pipe, this also selects linebreak.

If you don't want to select linebreak, use: `[^|\r\n]+`.

This will work in any text editor that support regex.

Comment: yes @Toto, I edit the topic. Your regex are good, but I must select only strings (words and numbers) between `<title>..</title>` tags For a python regex.

Comment: What is the meaning of  `#`? I would understand `=`. Is this some convention I don't know?

Comment: @JustMe: Please, edit your question with more examples and expected result for each one. I don't understand wwhat you really want to match. `#` in my answer is not part of regex, it is just introducing the meaning of the regex.

Comment: I know it's not the part of the regex. My point is it confuses my non-regex natural language parser. :)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: It's just an abit of mine, inside regex you can add comments that begin with `#` (if `(?x)` flag is turn on).

Comment: OK, so there is some convention I didn't know. I'm familiar with Bash where we can use `#` for commenting, still *outside of any code block* I don't expect `#` to introduce a comment. There's natural language outside formatted code, `#` just doesn't fit. I believe "this means 1 or more …" would be way more clear.

Comment: This is the line from my Python code, with the regex I must change a little bit: `words = re.findall(r'\w+', new_filename)`

Comment: @JustMe: OK, but this gives you an array. This is not what you asked in original question. You should explain more clearly what you want to do with context.